# Clone an object omitting nested property

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a copy of an existing object and omit some properties.  Is there an easy es6+ way of removing the nested bar key for the following structure?

```
  someObj = { 
    someList: [
      { foo:'1', bar:'x', /*etc could be more values*/ },
      { foo:'2', bar:'x', /*etc could be more values*/ },
      { foo:'3', bar:'x', /*etc could be more values*/ },
    ],
    otherPropOne: '',
    anotherProp: [],
    //etc
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the object then delete the variables you don't want in the copy. See this repl
https://repl.it/repls/NarrowWearyConstant

```
let someObj = { 
  someList: [
    { foo:'1', bar:'x', /*etc could be more values*/ },
    { foo:'2', bar:'x', /*etc could be more values*/ },
    { foo:'3', bar:'x', /*etc could be more values*/ },
  ],
  otherPropOne: '',
  anotherProp: [],
  //etc
}

let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj));
clone.someList = copy.someList.map((val, i) => {
  delete val.bar;
  // delete val.otherField
  return val;
})
console.log(someObj, clone);
```

Answer (score 4):

Make deep copy and remove unwanted fields

```
let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj)); 
clone.someList.forEach(x=> delete x.bar);
```

```js
let someObj = { 
    someList: [
      { foo:'1', bar:'x',  },
      { foo:'2', bar:'x',  },
      { foo:'3', bar:'x',  },
    ],
    otherPropOne: '',
    anotherProp: [],
    //etc
  }
  
let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj)); 
clone.someList.forEach(x=> delete x.bar);

console.log(clone);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 approach for a copy of an object

**ES6 Way**

You can easily copy of that object with spread operator(`...`)

```
    const mainObj = { id: 1 };
    const newObj = { ...mainObj };
```

But it's a shallow copy, So if you make any change in `newObj` It's replicated in `mainObj` too.

```js
  const mainObj = {
    someList: [
      { foo: '1', bar: 'x' },
      { foo: '2', bar: 'x' },
      { foo: '3', bar: 'x' }
    ],
    otherPropOne: '',
    anotherProp: []
  };
  
  const newObj = { ...mainObj };
  newObj.someList.forEach((f) => { delete f.bar; });
  console.log(mainObj, newObj);
```

**Native Way**

```
    const mainObj = { id: 1 };
    const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainObj));
```

> **Benefit**: Change in `newObj` doesn't affect on `mainObj`

```js
  const mainObj = {
    someList: [
      { foo: '1', bar: 'x' },
      { foo: '2', bar: 'x' },
      { foo: '3', bar: 'x' }
    ],
    otherPropOne: '',
    anotherProp: []
  };

  const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainObj));
  newObj.someList.forEach((f) => { delete f.bar; });
  console.log(mainObj, newObj);
```

Comment: How does that work for a nested structure like the above example?

Comment: The spread operator does a shallow copy. I think this would omit nested objects.

Comment: That's not true, keys containing objects will still be mutated on both objects

Comment: @AsafAviv Totally agreed with you, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First you need to clone the object, unfortunately there is no easy way to do this in es6.
A simple `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` should do the trick, unless you have cyclic dependencies.

```
let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj));
```

For removing the `bar` prop, you can use destructuring with `.map`:

```
copy.someList = copy.someList.map(({bar, ...otherProps}) => otherProps);
```

Full example:

```js
let someObj = {
  someList: [{
      foo: '1',
      bar: 'x',
    },
    {
      foo: '2',
      bar: 'x',
    },
    {
      foo: '3',
      bar: 'x',
    },
  ],
  otherPropOne: '',
  anotherProp: [],
  //etc
};

let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObj));
clone.someList = clone.someList.map(({bar, ...otherProps}) => otherProps);
console.log(clone);
```